# VBA UserForm Array

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Currently, I have an Excel spreadsheet with some data and a command button that creates a UserForm that displays a subset of that data. The UserForm has been designed in a way that makes the data easier to view. The problem that I'm having is that I would like the command button to make multiple instances of my UserForm so that each form can show a different set of data.

I'm pretty new to VBA so any suggestions or just a place for me to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `ShowModal` property of the `UserForm` is set to `False` as otherwise only one instance of the `UserForm` can be shown at once.

After that, it is as simple as:

```
Dim ufArray(0 To 4) As UserForm1
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 4
    Set ufArray(i) = New UserForm1
Next i

For i = 0 To 4
    Load ufArray(i)
    ufArray(i).Show
Next i
```

to show five independent copies of `UserForm1`